# Subscribe springboot web-socket with Postman

Tags: websocket, postman, spring-websocket, java-websocket

I have created a springboot websocket with a topic

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

and I have created a Controller to receive the message and publish it to the given topic

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;
    }
}
```

I was able to establish a connection with postman with the URL ws://localhost:8080/ws

[image]

But how can I receive messages that are published to the topics? How can I subscribe to a given topic to receive messages for the topic I subscribed